# page not found in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

i am new to django. this is the error i keep getting when i try to visit node.name page.
page not found Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/Category//

urls.py

```
Category/<category_id>/ [name='productlisting']
```

index.html

```
  {% load mptt_tags %}
      <ul class="root">
          {% recursetree listing %}
              <li>
                <a href="Category/{{ category_id }}/">{{ node.name }}</a>  

              </li>
          {% endrecursetree %}
      </ul>
```

urls.py

```
path('Category/<category_id>/',views.productlisting, name='productlisting'),
path('Category/<category_id>/product/<product_id>/',views.details, name='details'),
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First you have an extra ending `/` in the endpoint you are trying to hit.

This is not how we name urls in anchor tag. Please refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) on how to name url and how to use it in template

so basically idea is that you would name url in urls.py in following manner:

```
path('Category/<int:category_id>/',views.productlisting,name='productlisting'),
```

then you would use this url name in template as:

```
<a href="{% url 'productlisting' category.id %}">{{ node.name }}</a>
```

Comment: please add your urls.py as well !